# How to get a detached repository working

Tags: git, repository

I am just starting with git.  Using command line.  I created a working direcotry and then a repository inside it.  I have several transactions of add, commit etc for testing.  I then moved the repository to another folder.  The repository is intact as this works.

```
cd g:\GITREPO
git status
```

If I now go to the working directory, the git-dir command is not accepted.  What am I doing wrong ?

```
cd g:\GITTEST
git --git-dir=G:\GITREPO
```

I get no errors, just a dump of the help.  If I leave out the path then I get " No Directory Given ".  So I have the right command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"`git --git-dir=G:\GITREPO`" in itself is not a full git command:

- it calls `git`,
- it  instructs `git` the Git database is in `G:\GITREPO` (which it is not, by the way. It should more probably be in `G:\GITREPO\.git`),
- and... it does *not* tell `git` what do do (`status`? `fetch`? `checkout`? something?).

Comment: Aah, I had assumed it was telling it that this was the directory from now on.  That is going to be painful to state it in each command.  :-)  Thanks

Comment: @RohitGupta you could make an alias: `doskey gg=git --git-dir=G:\GITREPO\.git $*`. Then `gg status`